# nstextfield securetextentry

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, nstextfield, appkit

I am making a login page, when I get user input its fine. The credentials are going to be stored in a file. The values stored in file get set as the string of the `NSTextField`.
If I use `NSSecureTextField` the password is never seen by user when I read the values from my file. I searched but was unable to view the password in my UI. I want to know if there is any way to make the password visible in my `NSSecureTextField`. I just tried it with `NSTextField` but then the user can see passwords being entered.

Comment: I did not get your question. Are you looking to populate password field with the value read from file? If this is the case then you can do `NSString *mypassword=@"anoopvaidya007";
    [self.password setStringValue:mypassword];`

Comment: Actually iwas violating the concept.Now idea is clear.Thanks @Anoop your guess was right.

Answer (score 8):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678486/nstextfield-securetextentry#comment22296894_15678486) says if you would just like to set the value of an `NSSecureTextField` just use `setStringValue:` on it. If you would like to be able to read what is in the `NSSecureTextField` you can call `setEchosBullets:` and pass `false` to make it show the actual text.